# How to move Laravel in simple hosting?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I try to move Laravel project in simple hosting(PHP), but this hosting does not has SSH and command terminal.

Can I somehow to run this project in hosting?

Comment: If you set the database and configure your host to go to `public/` directory it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run all needed commands on local server (composer, migrate etc.) then move entire directory to the shared server and configure domain to directory with your project, for example:

```
/home/shared/laravel-project/public
```

On local server you can use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) (or [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html)) to export database, so then you can import database via for example phpmyadmin or phppgadmin on shared server.

Remember to change database configuration in .env file.

Comment: I uploaded all files in public directory, when I set DB configurations. Now I get white empty list

Comment: What list? You mean blank page? You have enabled APP_DEBUG in your .env file? What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Empty page, sorry mistake

Comment: APP_DEBUG=true    ,  PHP 5.4.45

Comment: Laravel 5.2 requires PHP >= 5.5.9, see requirements: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2#server-requirements

Comment: It was the main reason