# How to publish laravel project on internet?

Tags: laravel

I have finished the working prototype of my laravel project(MVC), but I never done publishing a project on internet? Is there up any tutorials or step by step to publish on internet for free, to practice at least one time how this kind of process is done?

I am fine with a **** domain and slow speed, just to learn how this thing is being done?

**Note:** I don't have absolutely no knowledge about the publishing thing, domains and so on ... :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move Laravel in simple hosting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874863/how-to-move-laravel-in-simple-hosting)

Comment: I don't have absolutely no knowledge about the publishing thing, domains and so on ... :(, where I can learn this stuff?

Comment: There a lots of tutorial on internet. Why don't you take some research first?

Comment: I don't know where to start :(

Comment: Get a cheap VPS, lowendbox can help here. Install ubuntu, connect through ssh, install nginx, php, mysql, git. Make sure you have your project on let's say github or bitbucket (this one has free private repo). Then on server pull project and configure nginx for it. Long way, but a lot better than shared hosting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of tutorials over internet which will guide you. I am giving some basic steps here:

1. Book one domain & hosting (check for providers like GoDaddy, BlueHost, Hostgator etc.)
2. Access cPanel (provider will give you credentials) and create FTP account.
3. Upload your files to root (i.e., under /public_html)

Comment: This is that step by step that I was looking for, thank you, I will try to implement. :)

Comment: Let me know if you need any further help :)